# Find table without name?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me write a function which will locate a table within a worksheet, without the table name given?

input: worksheet, or worksheet name

output: table, or table name

assumption: worksheet has only one table

Something along these lines:

```
Function GetTableName(shtName As String) As Boolean

    'Do stuff that returns the table name   

End Function
```

Comment: `ListObject("TheTableName")` seems inconsistent with "locate a table within a worksheet, without the table name given".  Clarify what you are asking exactly - given, expected, what you have tried, and what you get that differs from what you expect.

Comment: @J0e3gan I agree that statement seems inconsistent but the OP *did* provide given (input), expected (output) as well as what they were trying (code block).  I think the understanding is in how they phrased the question. Just my opinion FWIW :-)

Comment: @PortlandRunner: Fair enough. That makes sense.

Comment: @J0e3gan You're right, I'll update the code block to reflect my intent.  I was trying to print out as much code as I could to give whoever answered it more to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is always one table do this:

```
Sub findFirstTable()
    MsgBox "Table """ & Worksheets("shtName").ListObjects(1).Name & """ Found"
End Sub
```

---

If there are more than one tables, try looping through all "ListObjects" on the sheet and then return the name like this:

```
Sub FindAllTablesOnSheet()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set wks = Worksheets("shtName")

    For Each tbl In wks.ListObjects
        Application.Goto tbl.Range
        MsgBox "Table """ & tbl.Name & """ Found"
    Next
End Sub
```

---

To get your function working I changed a few things and had it return a string since it sounds like your looking for the name instead of trying to find out if it exist.  You should add some error handling if your sheet has no table on it.

```
Sub main()
    MsgBox "Table name: " & GetTableName("shtName")
End Sub

Function GetTableName(shtName As String) As String
    GetTableName = Worksheets(shtName).ListObjects(1).Name
End Function
```

---

Results of all three methods:

[image]